# python sqlite3 conditional query

Tags: python, sqlite

Sqlite3 table

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    p1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    p2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    p3 INTEGER NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO t (1, 11, 12, 13)
```

Python

```
def update(id, p1=None, p2=None, p3=None):
    db = self.get_db()
    db.execute('UPDATE t SET p1=?, p2=?, p3=? WHERE id=?', (p1, p2, p3, id))
```

When I use `update(1, 3, 4, 5)` it works, but on update(1, 3, 4) it gives me `Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: t.p3` what is normal because i should do

```
if not p3:
    db.execute('UPDATE t SET p1=?, p2=? WHERE id=?', (p1, p2, id))
```

Is it possible to get it done quite simple ?

for example:

```
stm = db.prep('UPDATE t SET')
if p1:
    stm.append('p1=?', p1)
if p2:
    stm.append('p2=?', p2)
if p3:
    stm.append('p3=?', p3)
stm.append('WHERE id=?', id)
```

Comment: ***"Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: t.p3"***: You only pass **tree** parameter, `update(1, 3, 4)`, the **fourth** will be `None` which is `p3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the easiest method I can think of:

```
def update(self, object_id, p1=None, p2=None, p3=None):  # don't use id as a variable name
    db = self.get_db()
    # if any of the parameters are None, set the new value to what it was already
    db.execute('UPDATE t SET p1=ifnull(?, p1), p2=ifnull(?, p2), p3=ifnull(?, p3) WHERE id=?', (p1, p2, p3, object_id))
```

Personally, I would use an ORM instead of raw SQL for security reasons.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: What if  there is default value like `p1 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT=55`. How can I use something like. UPDATE t SET p1=ifnull(?, DEFAULT) ... or maybe UPDATE t SET ifnotnull(?, p1=?). I know that there is no default nor second example, but maybe there is some other magical way :)